# How do i group by the contents of a string list using collect() of a Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a database object that has a field that contains a list of strings. I retrieve all these objects and then use the flatMap and distinct stream methods on the resulting list to get a new list that holds all possible unique values that a database object string list can contain.

Next i want to make a map where the keys are the unique values list of the stringlist that i made earlier, and the values of the map are a list of database objects whose stringlist contains the value of the respective string mapkey.

So what I want is groupingBy the following:

```
if(object.stringList().contains(respectiveMapKeyFromUniqeStringCollection) put object in object values list of that respective keymap.
```

Is something like this possible using the groupingBy method?

Edit: I will explain further

```
class VegetableMaker{
@ElementCollection  
private List<String> vegetableList;

}
```

Lets assume the possible values that a vegetableList can contain are: "Lettuce, Tomato, spinache, rubarbe, onion"

```
Set<String> produceNames = vegetableMakers.stream().flatMap(vegetableMaker -> vegetableMaker.getVegetableList().stream())
    .distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Now we have the list that contains all the possible values mentioned before.

We want to use the values in this list as the keys in the map.

So the Map will look like:

```
Map<uniqueStringsAsKeys, List<VegetableMaker>> map
```

The list value contains all the VegetableMaker instances of which the vegetableList contains the key of the map. So the list of key Onion will contain all the VegetableMaker instances whose list includes "Onion".

Is it possible to achieve such a map using the groupingBy method of a java stream?

EDIT 2:

This is the solution i have now, that doesn't use groupingBy but clarifies even more what I want.

EDIT: changed variable in code to match variables used in previous examples.

```
Set<VegetableMaker> vegetableMakers = vegetableMakerDao.findAll();
Set<String> uniqueVegetableList = vegetableMakers.stream().flatMap(vegetableMaker -> affiliateLink.getKeywords().stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
Map<String,Set<VegetableMaker>> vegetableMakersContainingKeywordInTheirList = new HashMap<>();

uniqueVegetableList.forEach(produceName ->{
    Set<VegetableMaker> vegetableMakerSet = new HashSet<>();
    vegetableMakers.forEach( vegetableMaker -> {
        if(vegetableMaker.getVegetableList().contains(produceName))
            vegetableMakerSet.add(vegetableMaker);
    });
    vegetableMakersContainingKeywordInTheirList.put(produceName, vegetableMakerSet);
});
```

Comment: Sample input List and the expected output would help a lot.

Comment: ive explained further, please view the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
List<VegetableMaker> dbObjects = List.of(
            new VegetableMaker("Salad", List.of("Onion", "Cucumber")),
            new VegetableMaker("Italian Salad", List.of("Cheese")),
            new VegetableMaker("Greek Salad", List.of("Onion")));

    Map<String, List<VegetableMaker>> map = dbObjects.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getVegetableList().stream().map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, y)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(map);
```

Resulting being something like:

```
{Onion=[Salad, Greek Salad], Cheese=[Italian Salad], Cucumber=[Salad]}
```

**EDIT**

This is not much different than what I posted above:

```
Map<String, Set<VegetableMaker>> result = vegetableMakerList.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getKeywords().stream().distinct().map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, y)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `x.getVegetableList().stream().distinct().map(...)`?

Comment: no VegetableMaker doesn't have a string field, just a List field with vegetable values. I have made a solution that doesn't use groupingBy but that may clarify even more what I want to achieve. In the code VegetableMaker is called AffiliateLink and the unique list of vegetables that should serve as keys is called produceNames, I will add the code to my OP now.

Comment: @Aominè this indeed would matter if you would have this `new VegetableMaker("Salad", List.of("Onion", "Cucumber", "Onion")` (Onion two times); but I've assumed two same ingredients can't be present...

Comment: i editted the code so that the variable names are now the same as the names used in the previous examples

Comment: Please tell me if my interpretation of your code is correct: First you flatmap the keywords while at the same time
turning those keywords into entries where the key is the affiliatelink, and the value is a unique keywords right?
So the SimpleEntry consists out of <AffiliateLink, String>.Then you group by the unique vegetables stored in the SimpleEntry
objects. Then for each vegetable key you map to a set with the AffiliateLink values. Am i right? I think this is a brilliant solution
and i've learned something new today, Thank you.

Comment: @Maurice that is correct, nothing brilliant though... just got used to stream API...

Comment: PS: @Eugene could you change AffiliateLinks to VegetableMakerList? I changed my code to conform to the variablenames i used in the example before, keeping the old name might cause confusion with future readers of this OP. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Maurice sorry, not going to change... As far as "future" readers, I really doubt that someone will search these kind of things. I've done two edits already, enough for a single question IMO ;)

Comment: ok no problem, i did the edit for you then. Hope you don't mind. Thanks again for your anwer.

Comment: @Eugene well there's certainly been a good number of problems like this on StackOverflow but I guess no one knows what exactly the question should be. however, the solution is always the same.

Comment: Your solution is a clean cut ! I really was unaware of Collectors#mapping static method.

Answer (score 1):

```
final Set<VegetableMaker> vegetableMakers = vegetableMakerDao.findAll();

final Map<String, Set<VegetableMaker>> vegetableMakersContainingKeywordInTheirList = vegetableMakers.stream()
    .map(VegetableMaker::getKeywords)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        vegetable -> vegetableMakers.stream()
          .filter(vegetableMaker -> vegetableMaker.getKeywords().contains(vegetable))
          .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    ));
```